# What is wrong with my code? Raw Input API with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, raw-input

I am trying to use Raw Input API with Qt so that I can record keyboard events and mouse events. However, this code was unsuccessful. I am also a beginner about Raw Input API.

I tried using a debugger and found out that WM_INPUT doesn't execute. Is there something wrong with Qt?

And also my MainWin just freezes.

main.cpp

```
    #include <QApplication>
#include "MainWin.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWin mainw;
    mainw.show();
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[2];
    rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    rid[0].usUsage = 0x02;
    rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;
    rid[0].hwndTarget = 0;

    rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    rid[1].usUsage = 0x06;
    rid[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;
    rid[1].hwndTarget = 0;


    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, 2, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)) == false)
        exit(-1);
    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWin.cpp

```
#include "MainWin.h"



MainWin::MainWin()
{

}


MainWin::~MainWin()
{
}

bool MainWin::nativeEventF(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)
{
    MSG * msg = (MSG*)message;
    switch (msg->message)
    {
    case WM_INPUT:
        qDebug() << "in";
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there something wrong in my implementation?

Comment: also tried RIDEV_INPUTSINK but nothong works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Where is MainWin.h?

Comment: What is `nativeEventF`, other than a typo for `nativeEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `RAWINPUTDEVICE::hwndTarget` field to 0, so you are not giving the Raw Input API a specific `HWND` to send `WM_INPUT` messages to.  Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagrawinputdevice):

> `hwndTarget`
>
> Type: HWND
>
> A handle to the target window. **If `NULL` it follows the keyboard focus.**

Does your Qt window ever gain keyboard focus?  If not, you are not going to receive any `WM_INPUT` messages.

It is usually best to provide a specific `HWND` for the `hwndTarget`, eg:

```
rid[index].hwndTarget = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(mainw.WinId());
```

If you need to receive the messages while that `HWND` does not have keyboard focus, then use the `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` flag:

```
rid[index].dwFlags = ... | RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
```